# django python: How to use the source instead of the egg?

Tags: python, django

I was having some issues with a Django app called "[django-categories](http://github.com/washingtontimes/django-categories)"

The developer told me to use the **source** instead of the **egg**.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the categories directory to your project directory(where all your other apps go) and add it to installed apps and run syncdb or schema migration and you should be up and running.

Comment: So using the source means not running the setup.py install but just copying the apps into your app directory on the pythonpath. Ok I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: I won't run setup.py unless I'm using virtualenv as it may overwrite older versions(if I've any) which may impact other projects. Also that directory can be copied anywhere on python path. There is no mandatory requirement for it to be in project directory but I would like to keep all apps I use under my project directory so I don't need to worry when I'm deploying.

Answer (score 1):

On the github page you link to, there's a "download source" link.  Use that to download a zip or tar archive, then unzip it and make sure that the "categories" directory is in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I have copied the categories folder and placed into my apps directory. Still getting the same error though. Guess I'll contact the developer again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your apps directory in your PYTHONPATH?